# Reverse_delete_rule circular import

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

If I have two models, `User` and `Address`, and they reference each other like this:

```
# usermodel.py
from address import Address
from mongoengine import *
class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    address = ReferenceField(Address)

# address.py
from mongoengine import *
class Address(Document):
     owner = ReferenceField('User', reverse_delete_rule=2)
```

I get the error message:

```
NotRegistered('`User` has not been registered in the document registry.
Importing the document class automatically registers it, has it been imported?',)
```

Can I set up a signal on one document and a reverse_delete_rule on another?   I believe this is happening because reverse_delete_rule needs to register the document.

Comment: You've edited code but not description. "If I have two models, `User` and `FriendRequest`" there is no `FriendRequest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by using the alternate notation for `reverse_delete_rule`:

```
User.register_delete_rule(Address, 'owner', CASCADE)
```

So the documents would be updated like this:

```
# usermodel.py
from address import Address
from mongoengine import *
class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    address = ReferenceField(Address)

User.register_delete_rule(Address, 'owner', CASCADE)

# address.py
from mongoengine import *
class Address(Document):
     owner = ReferenceField('User')
```